# SQL to structure data for a graph widget

Tags: sql, charts

I have a tricky usecase, where I am not sure if it can be solved via a SQL or there is a need of a procedure.
I want to create a cursor/view which shall feed a chart widget.

As example just the sum of all account balances of customers at a bank in a month.
So the chart will show the sum which was current for each day in this month.

The origin data is like the following:

```
Customer a  1000    12.07.2019 
Customer b  2000    01.07.2019 
Customer c  3000    01.08.2019 
Customer a  1200    04.08.2019 
Customer c  4000    08.08.2019 
Customer a  1500    14.08.2019
Customer c  2200    29.08.2019
```

So there is always one entry whenever there is a change in the account balance.
However, for the chart widget I need the values for each day of the month (e.g. August).
So at August 25th the sum of balances of all customers was 7500 (1500 (a) + 2000 (b) + 4000 (c)).
But there is no record for August 25th, it has to be created during the SQL execution in the cursor.

Maybe somebody has an idea how to solve this :)

Thx and BR,

Andrej

Comment: Sounds like you just need a date table with a row per day.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add Missing Dates in Running Total](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40616649/add-missing-dates-in-running-total)